# Get Friday's Data on Monday

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a query that, when it is run on Monday, it retrieves data from Friday. When it is another weekday, it should retrieve data of previous day.
At the moment I created this query, which works perfectly except on Monday:

```
Select sum(od.shippedqty) as SHIPPEDQTY
from orderdetail od, orders o
Where o.orderkey = od.orderkey
and to_char(o.actualshipdate, 'YYYYMMDD') = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD') -1
```

I have tried to do something with a case function and all kind of tips found on the web, but I did not manage to get it to work. 
Who can help me.

Comment: please show your work for friday (your case statement).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this query works OK for you, just change the `-1` at the very end with

```
   - case to_char(sysdate, 'Dy') when 'Mon' then 3 else 1 end
```

With that said - how are you subtracting 1 from a string? Oracle will convert that string back to a number for you, but that is not going to work correctly as dates.

Rather:

```
... and o.actualshipdate >= trunc(sysdate) - <expression from above>
    and o.actualshipdate <  trunc(sysdate) - <expression from above> + 1
```

This is better than using `trunc` on the left-hand side and comparing to `trunc(sysdate)`, because it allows the use of an index on `actualshipdate` (assuming there is one, as there should be if you run queries similar to this one often).

**Edit**: See MT0's comment below (thank you, MT0!). Of course, he is right; if the query may be used in non-English speaking locales, that may be a problem. Even with my suggested modification to the `where` clause, there is still a `to_char()` in the whole thing - in the `case` expression. That should be written as:

```
to_char(sysdate, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language = English')
```

Comment: You may need to explicitly define the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` as the 3rd argument of `TO_CHAR()` otherwise the query may give unexpected results in different locales.

Comment: Query is now built as: Select sum(od.shippedqty) as SHIPPEDQTY
from orderdetail od, orders o
Where o.orderkey = od.orderkey
and o.actualshipdate >= trunc(sysdate) - case to_char(sysdate, 'Dy') when 'Mon' then 3 else 1 end
and o.actualshipdate <  trunc(sysdate) - case to_char(sysdate, 'Dy') when 'Mon' then 3 else 1 end + 1. This looks like it is working as it should for now. No TERRITORY problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
CASE TRUNC( your_date ) - TRUNC( your_date, 'IW' )
  WHEN 0 THEN your_date - INTERVAL '3' DAY -- Monday
  WHEN 6 THEN your_date - INTERVAL '2' DAY -- Sunday
         ELSE your_date - INTERVAL '1' DAY -- Tuesday - Saturday
END AS previous_workday
```

Comment: @mathguy. Query is running without any error. Need to check on Monday if it will produce the correct data.

Comment: @MartijnDrohm - that's what you think. Try running it on February 1. The righthand side will be `'20170201' - 1` which is 20170200; the comparison will fail and you will get no rows returned.

Comment: @MT0 - The OP seems to be running the query on weekdays (not on Saturday or Sunday) so perhaps that's not needed. Also, Oracle will drop the single quotes around the *language*, but strictly speaking they shouldn't be there.

Comment: The usage of NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` here is IMO not correct, the `D` format (contrary to `DY` format) depends on [NLS_TERRITORY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#sthref376), which can't be overriden in to_char.  This makes the opticaly inferior usage of `DY`format the right choice.

Comment: Try with `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = America; select TO_CHAR( sysdate, 'D' , 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH' ) d,   TO_CHAR( sysdate, 'DY' , 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH' ) DY from dual; ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY=GERMANY; select TO_CHAR( sysdate, 'D' , 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH' ) d,   TO_CHAR( sysdate, 'DY' , 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH' ) DY from dual;`

Comment: I find the `IW`solution most elegant and safe. Learned a new thing today:)